# Dll process hook is not working

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to hook my KeyboardProc from dll into my created window using dll injection. I want to see message boxes when pressing keys with focused injected window, but my code is not working properly.

Injected window code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (lParam)
    {
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgs, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    LPCTSTR className = L"WNDCLASS";
    LPCTSTR windowName = L"Window";

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    memset(&wcex, 0, sizeof(wcex));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = className;
    wcex.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, className, windowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    MSG msg;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 
        msg.lParam;
}
```

dll code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

HHOOK hhkKb;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"DOWN", L"keyboard key down in dll", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"UP", L"keyboard key up in dll", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    return 
        CallNextHookEx(hhkKb, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Window");

            if (windowHandle == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Handle is null", MB_ICONERROR);
                return TRUE;
            }

            DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, NULL);
            hhkKb = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hModule, threadId);
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Success", L"Sucessfully injected dll", MB_ICONINFORMATION); //shows that message

            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkKb);
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I see "Sucessfully injected dll" message, but when I'm pressing keys into injected window, the KeyboardProc is not called, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> using dll injection

unclear how you do this dll injection, but based on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242729/dll-injection-with-local-keyboard-hook) can assume that you manually inject your dll by `CreateRemoteThread` to `LoadLibraryA`. and in any case call `SetWindowsHookEx` from dll entry point is error by sense.

formally if thread, which call `SetWindowsHookEx`, **exit** - hooks will be automatically removed. so can say that on exit thread indirect call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`. don't sure are this clear documented, but can be view in next simply test

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DbgPrint("%x>KeyboardProc(%x)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), wParam);

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

ULONG HookThread(PVOID threadId)
{
    DbgPrint("%x>HookThread(%x)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)threadId);
    if (HHOOK hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)threadId))
    {
        Sleep(10000);//10 sec
        //MessageBoxW(0,0,L"Close Me", MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, HookThread, (PVOID)(ULONG_PTR)GetCurrentThreadId(), 0,0))
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        MessageBoxW(0,0,L"Press Buttons here", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

first several seconds (*or until you close `MessageBoxW` L"Close Me" if chose this variant*) you can view dbgprint from `KeyboardProc` when you press buttons on first messagebox. after `HookThread` exit - no more `KeyboardProc` will be called.

so if you inject dll via `CreateRemoteThread` - this thread call `LoadLibrary`, then `SetWindowsHookEx` will be called in this thread, and finally thread just exit - and this remove effect of call `SetWindowsHookEx` - hook will be remove.

however if we use `SetWindowsHookEx` we not need manually inject dll to process. visa versa - this api special design for automatically inject dll to remote process. and of course you must not call `SetWindowsHookEx` from dll entry point - this is nonsense. you need call `SetWindowsHookEx` from remote process - as result your dll and will be injected to target process. reread [Installing and Releasing Hook Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx#installing_releasing)